# How to compare value from response body with value from global variable?

Tags: rest, postman

I want to check if one value from response body is the same like value from saved global environment.

This doesn't work for me

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

var id = jsonData.comments[0].id;
tests["Id from response body should be the same as saved in global variables"] = id == "{{comment_id}}";
```

Comment: can you do a console.log of id and one of comment_id ? are you sure your global variable is well set ?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing an '=' in your assertion?
The main issue is probably that there is a 'conflict' between your stringified environment variable and the (I assume) string id you're comparing it to, making both not exactly the same and therefore failing the assertion.

The following should definitely work:

```
tests["Id from response body should be the same as saved in global variables"] = id === pm.environment.get("comment_id");
```

Comment: I would also leave out the variable id declaration and directly compare jsonData.comments[0].id with the stored environment var.